# Handling SQL join via timezone

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, timezone

I need to join two tables. The join has to be handled using parameter @timezone.
But there is a catch - @timezone's value can be null, '', ' ' or anything else. User can enter everything.

If @timezone's value is null the outcome of the join will be basically nothing.
So that, if it happens, there has to be at least basic value to join (for example, 'Pacific Standard Time')

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2022-01-20', @EndDate DATE = '2022-01-30', @t1 INT = 12345, @timezone VARCHAR(max) = NULL, @OnlyActivated INT = 0
SELECT r.ChargeType, r.CustomerName, r.PurchaseDate, r.accountID
FROM table_report as r
LEFT JOIN [sys].[time_zone_info] tzi ON tzi.[name] = @timezone (???)
```

I tried `IIF(@timezone IN (NULL,'',' '),'Pacific Standard Time',@timezone)` and it worked with '' and ' ' scenarios but then I realized that null can't be compared.

Maybe there is a pretty obvious solution but I don't see it.

Hope you can help with that.

P.S. CURRENT_TIMEZONE_ID() is not supported.

Comment: You need to left join twice, once for `@timezone` and again for the default, with a condition `AND tzi1.name IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @Charlieface 
`LEFT JOIN [sys].[time_zone_info] tzi ON tzi.[name] = IIF(@timezone IN ('',' '),'Pacific Standard Time',@timezone)
LEFT JOIN [sys].[time_zone_info] tzi1 ON tzi1.[name] = ISNULL(@timezone,'Pacific Standard Time') AND tzi1.name IS NOT NULL` like that?

Comment: No given your alias of `tzi` for the first join, you need `AND tzi.name IS NOT NULL`. The second join needs to check if the first one succeeded, you don't want to actually join the row if yiou already joined it. I usually do `tzi1` and `tzi2` aliases to make things a bit clearer

Comment: @Charlieface To be honest I actually don't understand what should be behind the second left join.

Comment: @Charlieface 
`LEFT JOIN [sys].[time_zone_info] tzi1 ON tzi1.[name] = IIF(@timezone IN ('',' '),'Pacific Standard Time',@timezone) AND tzi1.[name] IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN [sys].[time_zone_info] tzi2 ON tzi2.[name] = ???`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to left-join twice to do this. The second join needs to have a condition that it only executes if the first join does not succeed.

```sql
DECLARE
    @StartDate DATE = '2022-01-20',
    @EndDate DATE = '2022-01-30',
    @t1 INT = 12345,
    @timezone VARCHAR(max) = NULL,
    @OnlyActivated INT = 0;

SELECT
  r.ChargeType, r.CustomerName, r.PurchaseDate, r.accountID,
  ISNULL(tzi1.SomeValue, tzi2.SomeValue)
FROM table_report as r
LEFT JOIN [sys].[time_zone_info] tzi1 ON tzi1.[name] = @timezone
LEFT JOIN [sys].[time_zone_info] tzi2 ON tzi2.[name] = 'Pacific Standard Time'
    AND tzi1.[name] IS NOT NULL;
```

An alternative, if you are only worrying about `NULL` is to just `ISNULL` the variable

```sql
DECLARE
    @StartDate DATE = '2022-01-20',
    @EndDate DATE = '2022-01-30',
    @t1 INT = 12345,
    @timezone VARCHAR(max) = NULL,
    @OnlyActivated INT = 0;

SELECT
  r.ChargeType, r.CustomerName, r.PurchaseDate, r.accountID,
  tzi.SomeValue
FROM table_report as r
LEFT JOIN [sys].[time_zone_info] tz1 ON tzi.[name] = ISNULL(@timezone, 'Pacific Standard Time');
```

Comment: Yeah, got it. With all that crap that is happening nowadays it's difficult even to think.
Appreciate your patience and help. Have a nice day!